# how to integrate yii2 with ispconfig3

Tags: nginx, installation, centos, yii2

IspConfig3 uses /var/www/website/web as the default webroot.

When using yii2 Advanced App, should I place all the code above the webroot and simply create a simlink to the frontend/web as the web webroot?

How have others done this?

What if I'd like to install the yii2 application into a sub-directory of an application that already lives in the webroot?

ie:

```
location / {
  mainapp
  ---
}
location /yii2app {
  #can't get these setting right for frontend OR backend.
}
```

My server is centos 6.4 with nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move index.php (and .htaccess) from the frontend/web to any place you want. Just change the paths in it and it should work just fine. I did this in Yii1 and I see no reason why it would not work in yii2.

Comment: Thank you Mihai.  Nice n simple.  Also had to transfer the assets folder and css folder over as well.  So really everything in the frontend/web and backend/web to their own directories (or webroot) for ISPConfig3 to work as expected.